# How can I solve this system of equation?

Tags: quadratics

I ham given the following problem to solve:

> *1.9. The program should take three numbers: a; b; c and find the roots of the quadratic equation in the form:*
>
> [image]
>
> *If the value of the determinant of the quadratic equation is negative
>   (i.e. ∆ <0), the program should write an appropriate message.*
>
> *1.10. Modify the 1.9 so that the parameters A and a are functions of the parameter ϕ, e.g.*
>
> [image]
>
> *In the program, declare functions for the above equations and save the results in an array.*

---

I have solved the 1.9 as that was easy.  But I am stuck with the following:

$f(x) = f(1 + 0.25 \sin(x)) \tag 1$
$g(x) = g(1 + 0.5 |\sin(x)|) \tag 2$

My attempt ([source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1019223/366312)):

Given,

$f(x) = f(1 + 0.25 \sin(x))$

Now,

$f(1 + 0.25 \sin(x)) = \frac{a}{16} \sin^2{x} +\left (\frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{4}\right) \sin{x} + (a+b+c)$

Let, $\sin{x} = y$

So, the above equation becomes: $y = \frac{-(2a+b) \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}  {2a}$

Hence,

$\begin{align} \sin{x} &= \dfrac{-(2a+b) \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \\ x &= \sin^{-1}{\left (\dfrac{-(2a+b) \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \right)} \end{align}$

---

Are this procedure and solution correct?

Comment: Is [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1019223/721644) _your_ attempt?

Comment: @ms._VerkhovtsevaKatya, no, I followed the procedure used in the source.

Comment: In its current form, it is not clear what do mean for "solve". Are you trying to 1) find a function $f(x)$ that satisfies the functional equation $f(x) = f(1 + \frac14\sin x)$ for all $x$ or 2) given a specific $f(x)$ (some quadratic polynomial?), find a $x$ that satisfy the same equation.

Comment: @achillehui, **solve** means: "find the value of $x$".

Comment: @user366312:  It is *impossible* "to find the value of $x$" when $f$ is not given, unless $f$ is entirely superfluous.  (If so, why oh why is it included in the question?!?!)

Comment: Where does the line after Now come from?  Why should $f$ have that form?  The question you link had a condition that made it reasonable to expect its $f$ to be polynomial.  Yours does not.

Comment: @user366312: can you clarify what is the closed formula for $f$?

Comment: @Matteo, what do mean by closed formula?

Comment: @user366312: for example $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is a closed formula.

Comment: @Matteo, I asked my teacher about this. he says that it is about Maxwell's distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Problem 1.10 is almost as simple as Problem 1.9. The only difference is that the parameters  $a$ and $b$ or $c$ (there is no parameter $A$ in Problem 1.9, so this should be a misprint) instead of *constant* values are functions of the parameter $\varphi$ declared in the program (so a program solving Problem 1.10  can be a small modification of the program solving Problem 1.9). A solver has the freedom to choose the functions.

The equality $A(\phi)=A(1.0+0.25\sin(\phi))$ is *not* an equation to solve, it is an example of a function of a parameter $\varphi$. A bit confusing here is that $A$ from the left-hand side is a name of a function and the left-hand side equals to value of $A$ of the argument $\varphi$, whereas $A$ from the right side is a constant and the right-hand side is a *product* of this $A$ by $1.0+0.25\sin(\phi)$. Similarly for the other equality.